# Are there laws of creation for biological life?

Tags: biology, exoplanets

I am no scientist, but I do love science as well as the unknown. Are there laws of creation for biological life? Would it be safe to assume that our bodies are made up from things that came directly out of the big bang and over time made connections through atoms and adjustments through evolution to achieve consciousness? I have much more but I'll keep it as simple as I can for now.

Comment: *If space was a tree and I was light energy on one side and you was dark energy on the other would we cut the tree down?* I can’t make sense of that question.

Comment: _If space was a tree and I was light energy on one side and you was dark energy on the other would we cut the tree down?_ What does that mean?

Comment: The first two questions are sensible but the third question (about the tree) was just nonsense so I have removed it.

Comment: Voting to re-open. Once the nonsense question was removed there is nothing off-topic or non-mainstream here.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there laws of creation for biological life?

As far as we know, the laws that govern the creation of life are exactly the same as the physical and chemical laws that apply to the rest of the universe. There are no "laws" that are specific to living things.

> Would it be safe to assume that our bodies are made up from things that came directly out of the big bang and over time made connections thru atoms and adjustments thru evolution to achieve consciousness?

If you go down to the level of quarks and electrons them, yes, the constituents of our bodies came out of the big bang - but there is long chain of events after that. Over time the quarks combined into protons and neutrons (nucleons); these nucleons then combined with electrons to form atoms of hydrogen, helium and lithium; some of those elements were transformed in supernovae to form heavier elements such as carbon and oxygen; the atoms of these elements joined together to form simple molecules such as water and methane; and eventually through the processes of chemistry and biochemistry these molecules combined and recombined to form more complex molecules and eventually living things.